# How can I perfectly truncate a string in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, truncate

I am reading from a file of which each line is longer than 63 characters and I want the characters to be truncated at 63. However, it fails to truncate the lines read from the file.

In this program we are assuming that the file has 10 lines only:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[10][63];
    char line[255];

    int count = 0;

    //Open file                
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("lines.dat", "r"); 

    //Read each line from file to the "line array"
    while(fgets(line, 255,fp) != NULL)
    {
        line[63] = '\0';

        //copy the lines into "a array" char by char
        int x;
        for(x = 0; x < 64; ++x)
        {
            a[count][x] = line[x];
        }

        count++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    //Print all lines that have been copied to the "a array"
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", a[i]);
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to include the null character: `for (x = 0; x < 21; x++)`

Comment: where should I put the character. Forgive me I am new to C. Thanks @grc

Comment: Just use `for (x = 0; x < 21; x++)` as suggested by @grc

Comment: strncpy (a[0], line, 20); - saves the hassle with \0 and for loop.

Comment: `a[0]` needs a null character to terminate the string. Since you've put one at `line[20]`, you can copy it across by letting the for loop run once more at `x = 20`.

Comment: You seem to be asking how to copy a string, not how to truncate one.

Comment: if you just want 63 chars, why not ask fgets to do the job ? `fgets(a[i++], 63 , fp)`

Comment: @Orel: that would be `65` then. Also, `fgets` handles too long lines in unexpected ways: you need to check its return value and result string, and if signalled 'too long' do more `fgets`es until an EOF or newline is encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this result because you forgot to add the null string terminator in the end of a[0].

There's several ways to do it. My favorite one is to leave line as is: since it seems you want the truncated string elsewhere, you souldn't modify the source.
In that case, you can replace:

```
//Tries to truncate "line" to 20 characters
line[20] = '\0';

//copying line to each character at a time
int x;
for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    a[0][x] = line[x];
}
```

with

```
//copying line to each character at a time
int x;
for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    a[0][x] = line[x];
}
a[0][20] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing the null byte.

You can get more info about this at : [Null byte and arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161921/null-byte-and-arrays-in-c)

Comment: You should post this as a comment, not as an answer. If you want this to become an answer, explain it in the post rather than just providing a link.