# How to cut or truncate lines from a text file in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, truncate

I am reading from a file of which each line is greater than 63 characters and I want the characters to be truncated at 63. However, it fails to truncate the lines read from the file.

In this program we are assuming that the file has 10 lines

**Goal:** I want to read 63 characters from each line. Any line that has more than 63 characters, 63 characters are read and the rest are truncated. If there is an easier way to do this please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[10][63];
    char line[255];

    int count = 0;

    //Open file                
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("lines.dat", "r"); 

    //Read each line from file to the "line array"
    while(fgets(line, 255,fp) != NULL)
    {
        line[63] = '\0';

        //copy the lines into "a array" char by char
        int x;
        for(x = 0; x < 64; ++x)
        {
            a[count][x] = line[x];
        }

        count++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    //Print all lines that have been copied to the "a array"
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", a[i]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question as your previous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793054/how-can-i-perfectly-truncate-a-string-in-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Weather Vane mentioned, your `char` matrix is not quite wide enough to accomodate lines with 63 characters *plus* the final `'\0'`.

There are other problems with your code:

- You read lines with `fgets(line, 255,fp)`, then force a `'\0'` after 63 characters.  What if the line has more than 254 bytes?  The rest of the line would stay unread in stdin until the next call, and you will have one or multiple extra erroneous line chunks in your matrix.
- You do not handle the linefeed characters at the end of the lines: if a line is truncated, it does not have a `'\n'` in the matrix, whereas it does for shorter lines.
- What should you do with lines shorter than 63 characters?  ignore them?  skip them?  I know you assume they all have at least 63 characters, but your program should handle non conforming input gracefully and predictably.

Here is a modified program to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NROWS  10
#define NCOLS  63
int main(void)
{
    char a[NROWS][NCOLS+1];
    int row, col, c;

    //Open file                
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("lines.dat", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 1;

    for (row = 0; row < NROWS;) {
        for (col = 0; (c = getc(fp)) != EOF;) {
            if (c == '\n')
                break;
            if (col < NCOLS)
                a[row][col++] = c;
        }
        //terminate the string.
        a[row][col] = '\0';
        if (col == 0 && c == EOF)
            break;
        if (col < NCOLS) {
            // handle short lines: here just accept them.
        }
        row++;
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    //Print all lines that have been copied to the "a array"
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

I you insist on using `fgets`, here is an alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NROWS  10
#define NCOLS  63
int main(void)
{
    char a[NROWS][NCOLS+1];
    char *p;
    int row, c;

    //Open file                
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("lines.dat", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 1;

    for (row = 0; row < NROWS;) {
        if (!fgets(a[row], NCOLS+1, fp))
            break; // stop at EOF
        if ((p = strchr(a[row], '\n')) != NULL)
            *p = '\0';  // accept short lines
        row++;
        // skip extra characters upto the end of line
        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    //Print all lines that have been copied to the "a array"
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked really fine. Though I was not planning to skip the short lines. So If I wanted to include shorter lines what should I do?

Comment: If you want to include the short lines, in the first version, just remove the test and increment `row` in all cases.  For the second version, you need to overwrite the `'\n'` with a `'\0'` instead of skipping the line with `continue`.  I edited the response.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not big enough to hold 63 characters **and** the string terminator.

```
char a[10][63];
```

should be

```
char a[10][64];
```

Then you can properly index the string by `63` as the index range is `0`..`63`.

An easier way to copy the string into your array would be with a library function, you will need to `#include <string.h>`

```
while(fgets(line, 255, fp) != NULL)
{
    line[63] = '\0';
    strcpy (a[count], line);
    count++;
}
```